# Why isn't there a "Medium Small Black Circle" in Unicode

Tags: unicode

I know this is maybe off-topic on SO, but I don't know where else to ask. The Unicode blocks [Miscellaneous Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols) and [Miscellanous Symbols and Arrows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols_and_Arrows_(Unicode_block)) contain these characters:

- HEAVY LARGE CIRCLE (U+2B55) ⭕ (before emojis it used to look like ◯)
- BLACK LARGE CIRCLE (U+2B24) ⬤
- MEDIUM WHITE CIRCLE (U+26AA) ⚪
- MEDIUM BLACK CIRCLE (U+26AB) ⚫
- WHITE CIRCLE (U+25CB) ○
- BLACK CIRCLE (U+25CF) ●
- MEDIUM SMALL WHITE CIRCLE (U+26AC) ⚬

But there is no MEDIUM SMALL *BLACK* CIRCLE. Why is that? Is there an alternative for this symbol? (Ie. the same size as its white counterpart?)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to the annotations in the chart for the [Geometric Shapes Extended](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F780.pdf) block, the set of differently sized black circles is ordered as follows:

1. `U+22C5` DOT OPERATOR (⋅)
2. `U+2219` BULLET OPERATOR (∙)
3. `U+1F784` BLACK SLIGHTLY SMALL CIRCLE ()
4. `U+2022` BULLET (•)
5. `U+2981` Z NOTATION SPOT (⦁)
6. `U+26AB` MEDIUM BLACK CIRCLE (⚫︎)
7. `U+25CF` BLACK CIRCLE (●)
8. `U+2B24` BLACK LARGE CIRCLE (⬤)

⋅∙•⦁⚫︎●⬤

Therefore, DOT OPERATOR serves as *tiny black circle*, BULLET OPERATOR serves as *very small black circle*, BULLET serves as *small black circle*, and Z NOTATION SPOT serves as *medium small black circle*.

These unifications with existing characters were implemented to cut down on the number of new additions needed when Wingdings/Webdings were incorporated into the standard.

Comment: Medium black circle (⚫︎) is the one that most closely resembles a Markdown bullet.

Comment: However, since it gets converted to an emoji on macOS, I would use the Z notation spot (⦁) instead.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an alternative for this symbol?

Try • ∙ ⦁

> Why is that?

In the past, Unicode just collected existing character repertoires. If the originating did not have a medium small black circle, then for round-trip reasons Unicode would not have one, either.

You can get a definitive answer on the [appropriate mailing list](https://www.unicode.org/consortium/distlist-unicode.html).